# How do I access a picture box on a form from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

My form (Form1) has a picture box, which I need to access from another class (Logic.cs).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a public property for it.

Assuming your picture box is called `pictureBox1`, then write this property inside form1:

```
public PictureBox MyPictureBox
{
    get
    {
        return pictureBox1;
    }
}
```

From inside your other class you will need a reference to the form. If it is called `myForm` you would access the picture box as `myForm.MyPictureBox;`

If your Logic class doesn't have a reference to the form, you will need to supply it. If the class that creates the Logic class also creates the form, it can pass a reference to the Logic class.

It would be better, if your Logic class *only* requires the PictureBox, to pass the PictureBox to it rather than the whole form.

Something like: `Logic logic = new Logic(form1.MyPictureBox);`

so that only the PictureBox part is passed to Logic's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass you Form1 PictureBox as a parameter to Logic.cs in constructor

Example:

**Form1**  when you call login.cs

```
login t = new test(this.pictureBox1);
t.Show();
```

in **login.cs** counstructor

```
    PictureBox s;
    public login(PictureBox p)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        s = p;
    }
```

you can do it in to login.cs make a picture box and the pass it to From1